# How to import a non-TypeScript module by relative path?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following file structure:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── b
    ├── package.json
    └── index.js
```

`a` is a TypeScript module, `b` is a plain JavaScript module.

a/src/main.ts contains the following code:

```js
import {helloB} from "../../b";
console.log("Hello from A!");
helloB();
```

b/index.js contains the following code:

```js
module.exports.helloB = function() {
    console.log("Hello from B!");
};
```

I would like to import `b` from `a` using a relative import. I've tried importing `../../b` as specified above but got the following error:

```
src/main.ts:1:22 - error TS6059: File '/home/ivanq/Documents/tstest/b/index.js' is not under 'rootDir' '/home/ivanq/Documents/tstest/a/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

1 import {helloB} from "../../b";
```

I could add `b` to `rootDir` but I do not want TypeScript to compile that module and output it to build directory. I want it to do `require("../../b")` in runtime, like it does with files inside `node_modules`. How do I configure TypeScript to do that?

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html

Comment: I've read that article but, according to the docs, I have to add tsconfig to module b and generate .d.ts files, i.e. build and type-check the JS module with TypeScript, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I want to replicate the behavior of symlinking `b` to `a/node_modules/b` and using `import ... from "b"`, but without ugly filesystem manipulation.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are trying to do this. Is there some other pressure on/consumer of that JS module?

Comment: That module is actually not mine. I'd like to make a few modifications, but I don't want to introduce incompatible changes like adding new configuration files or rebuilding the module with TypeScript.